# HTML CSS exersice, simple (just to understand the task)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to change the form of this page http://dubailifestyleapp.com/members/. according to the following steps:

add this link inside the

```
 <head>
<link rel="stylesheet" 
    href="https://trafficbalance.io/static/css/sdk/sdk.css">
```

-then to add these js link and also the script:

```
<script src="https://trafficbalance.io/static/js/sdk/all.min.js">
</script>
  <script>
  $(function() {
  tbsdk.init({
    container: '#cont',
pipe: '0rSX2a2',
 campaign: '13',
sub_campaign: '30DayChange',
  password_required: true,
    extra_data: {
  subAffiliateId: "30DayChange"
  }
   });
   });
  </script>
```

and to change the div of the form to

```
<div id=“cont”></div>
```

I change all of these, and nothing was change in the form of the webpage.
I guess I need to use the Javascript function for the form, how can I use it?

Answer (score 1):

So first you need to Duplicate http://dubailifestyleapp.com and 
 http://dubailifestyleapp.com/members/

Then on the first page Change the form to only a button that redirect to 
  the members page

Then, on the members page change the form to this form :
inside :

```
  before </body> closes:
```

if jQuery is already in page, no need to add this line.

```
$(function() {
    tbsdk.init({
    container: '#cont',
    pipe: '0rSX2a2',
    campaign: '13',
    sub_campaign: '30DayChange',
    password_required: true,
    extra_data: {
    subAffiliateId: "30DayChange"
}
});
});
```

And the last thing you should do is put this div instead of the original form

```
<div id=“cont”></div>
```

Comment: what does  it mean  on the members page change the form to this form :       3)on the members page change the form to this form :
inside <head>:
 <link rel="stylesheet" 
      href="https://trafficbalance.io/static/css/sdk/sdk.css">

  before </body> closes:
   <script src="https://trafficbalance.io/static/js/lib/jquery.min.js"> ok I set all those instructions but nothing changed on the form it's all the same, what am I missing here?

Comment: I'll be honest with you bud. Your question didn't make sense. You got downvoted because it sounded like you wanted other to do your homework. I literally copied and pasted what you said. See if you can explain better what you need and I'll see if I can help. Edit your question.