# how to change existing form

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi I have some existing web page
I need to duplicate the page and then to change the form to this form :
inside

```
<head>:
<link rel="stylesheet" 
  href="https://trafficbalance.io/static/css/sdk/sdk.css">

 before </body> closes:
  <script src="https://trafficbalance.io/static/js/lib/jquery.min.js">
</script> if jQuery is already in page, no need to add this line.
 <script src="https://trafficbalance.io/static/js/sdk/all.min.js"></script>
 <script>
   $(function() {
   tbsdk.init({
container: '#cont',
 pipe: '0rSX2a2',
 campaign: '13',
 sub_campaign: '30DayChange',
  password_required: true,
  extra_data: {
   subAffiliateId: "30DayChange"
  }
  });
 });
</script>
```

and to put this div instead of the original form:

```
  <div id=“cont”></div>
```

I don’t understand what does it mean to change the existing from to this form:

`<link rel="stylesheet" 
    href="https://trafficbalance.io/static/css/sdk/sdk.css">`
    this is an css file, any one can please explain me what does it mean?
     thanks!

Comment: The link tag will be used to get css file. https://www.w3schools.com/Tags/tag_link.asp

Comment: your html seems off. can you please edit that.

Comment: `id=“cont”` will cause the ID to be `“cont”`, literally. You want `id="cont"`.

Comment: ye I understand that but there is no change if I put this link tag and changing the div  to "cont"

Comment: the page is the same

Comment: this is the page that I need to duplicate http://dubailifestyleapp.com/members/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML CSS exersice, simple (just to understand the task)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45859804/html-css-exersice-simple-just-to-understand-the-task)

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear, but i think i got it.
There's a CSS rule called "cascade", wich means that more specific styles overrite the generic ones, so, you can specify a style to your `<div>` element by adding

```
<style>
    div{
        style propeperties
    }
</style>
```

or

```
<style>
    #elementId{
        style propeperties
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but my problem is that this ID named "cont" doesn't exist in https://trafficbalance.io/static/css/sdk/sdk.css so I couldn't understand this task

Comment: It doesn´t need to, you can add a style property inside your HTML file, probably #cont is a unique ID to this file, so, it would be a waste to add a style for it on the generic CSS file

Comment: ok I see, so now I'm confused, what are the uses of this file in the task?

Comment: It sets a basic style to your HTML file, so if you don't contradict it, it will be aplied to your file, but if you set new styles, the new ones will overrite the generic ones. More info: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

Comment: I understand what you say but I can't understand this task, this is the page that I need to duplicate and to change the form:http://dubailifestyleapp.com/members/ I Changed the ID of the form to "cont" and I insert the <script> that I wrote above but nothing changing in the site